# MySQL - Display all dates including zero data nested join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display all dates in a month, and also in the reservation detail, I only have check_in_date and check_out_date, so I have to create left join inside a left join, below is my script

```
SELECT
    *                   
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        @dt:= DATE_ADD( @dt, interval 1 day ) myDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
                @dt := '2020-01-31'
    ) vars, tb_dummy
            LIMIT 29
) JustDates 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(d.myDate2,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `myDate2`,
        COALESCE(count(rdt.reservation_detail_id), 0) AS `RNS`,
        FORMAT(SUM(rdt.subtotal_amount/COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DATE(DATE(rdt.check_out_date)), DATE(rdt.check_in_date)), 0)), 2) AS `REVENUE`,
        FORMAT(SUM(rdt.subtotal_amount/COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DATE(DATE(rdt.check_out_date)), DATE(rdt.check_in_date)), 0))/COALESCE(count(rdt.reservation_detail_id), 0), 2) AS `AVGREV`        
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            @dt:= DATE_ADD( @dt, interval 1 day ) myDate2
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                    @dt := '2020-01-31'
        ) vars2, tb_dummy
            LIMIT 29
    ) d
    LEFT JOIN 
        tb_reservation_detail rdt 
    ON d.myDate2 BETWEEN DATE(rdt.check_in_date) AND DATE(DATE(rdt.check_out_date) - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    INNER JOIN 
        tb_reservation R 
    ON rdt.reservation_id = R.reservation_id
    WHERE 
        rdt.reservation_status_id <> 3
    AND
        R.property_id = 57
    GROUP BY d.myDate2
    ORDER BY d.myDate2 ASC
)   Resv
    ON
        JustDates.myDate = Resv.myDate2
ORDER BY
    JustDates.myDate ASC
```

when i run it only return dates from the left table like : [Left join result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9LTS.png)

but when I change

```
SELECT
    *                   
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        @dt:= DATE_ADD( @dt, interval 1 day ) myDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
                @dt := '2020-01-31'
    ) vars, tb_dummy
            LIMIT 29
) JustDates 
**LEFT JOIN**
(
```

to

```
SELECT
    *                   
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        @dt:= DATE_ADD( @dt, interval 1 day ) myDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
                @dt := '2020-01-31'
    ) vars, tb_dummy
            LIMIT 29
) JustDates 
**RIGHT JOIN**
(
```

it returns data from the right table like this: [Right join result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Yig.png)

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow. I think your problem is that you don't quite understand the difference between `RIGHT JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`. Check out [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) that goes over the differences.

As far as wanting to display all of the dates in a month, here's a [link to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300664/mysql-how-to-show-all-days-records-in-particular-month/60536438#60536438) I posted that I believe does what you want it to. In my answer I provide an example query that contains a derived table you can select from and then `LEFT JOIN` your tables to so it will show all the days in the month regardless if there is data in your tables for a given day or not.

Hope this helps.